Turbo triggers erratically on a Renault Scenic
I have a Renault Scenic III 1.5 dCi (95ch) from 2012. Since a few months, the motor occasionally starts to rev at a high RPM. As soon as I release the gas, it calms down, but sometimes when I press the gas again just a little, it immediately starts to turn too high again. It then somehow calms down after a few seconds of behaving like that, and run normally again. It sometimes goes up to 3500 RPM, which is somewhat scary. It often happens when upshifting in 4th or 5th gear. It also happens more often when I go uphill, or need to overtake. It can also occur randomly when I push the gas just a bit more.
This makes the driving very confusing. It forces me to go very easy on the gas, and be very careful. This certainly isn't fully detrimental compared to my usual driving style, but overtaking now becomes a challenge. I often find myself with the motor screaming at 2700 RPM, in 5th gear, but going at 70kph. I don't even understand where the revving vanishes.
I guess the turbo, or some stuff related to the turbo triggering, is broken.
Given the age and state of that car, I don't want to put much money in it, so I was trying to consider other options than going to the mechanic and hearing I need to put 700€ on the table to get it repaired.
I have a few questions:

Could this be, indeed, just the turbo, or may the cause be something else?
Is it some typical problem from this motor that has a solution with high chances of succeeding, is easy to do, and cheap? (Don't worry, I already expect a "Lol, no." answer here).
Can the turbo be easily disabled alltogether, so I avoid this problem entirely? I don't need that card to drive fast, I just need it to drive, and behave in a predictable manner. That turbo has always been a disappointment anyway.
If it is possible, what are the consequences, beside the obvious lack of power? Can it have effects on other components, longevity of other parts, etc... Will there be any red light constantly shown on the dashboard? May it prevent the roadworthiness testing (I'm in France)?


"Lol, no." This is not a turbo problem, and disabling the turbo will not fix it. You mentioned rpm changing but you did not mention sudden crazy acceleration, and that suggests that the transmission is changing to a lower gear when that is not your intention. (1) Is this a traditional automatic trans or is it a CVT? (2) Is there an indicator or light on your instrument panel that shows what gear is presently engaged? (3) Does it change to a lower number when the rpm suddenly goes crazy? Someone with more experience with this vehicle may reply after you provide this info.

It is a manual, and I think the answer given below may be fully right.

Yes, I agree completely!

This doesn't sound turbo-related at all - if this is a manual transmission car (which going by you describing it as a 95ch I'm assuming it is - the auto only came with the 110hp engine I believe) then I'd say this sounds like classic signs of a worn/failing clutch that's slipping. That's good news! As this is probably your best-case scenario, while not cheap per se a clutch replacement is substantially less than, say, a borked turbo.
If it is an automatic then IIRC the auto gearbox used in these was Renault's own Dual Clutch implementation (EDC) - so it could still be the same cause, i.e. a slipping clutch. But the inherent extra complexity of a gearbox of this nature will make diagnosis a bit trickier and the associated parts and work far more expensive. To the extent that on this age and model of vehicle it's unlikely to be economical to repair - a clutch kit for the manual is about €170, the clutch kit for the EDC 'box is about ten times that much!

Good answer +1.

Thank you. It is indeed a manual, and what you describe is very clear, and makes total sense. I'll give it to a mechanic and hope he'll make it for a reasonable price.
